# Migrate to hoisted imports

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, circular-dependency

so I recently have moved to esm based modules for swc. Everything is alright except my app relied on import statements not being hoisted up top, basically in my `index.ts` I export a variable that is used in the imported module.

```
// index.ts

export const a = {foo: "bar"};
import {b} from "./blah/b";
```

```
// b.ts

import {a} from "../index";
export const b = a.foo;
```

So when I run this code I get `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization`. Because the import is hoisted to the top in `index.ts`. Which means `b.ts` code executes first. How can I solve this without going back to CommonJS? I'm really fed up with this importing and exporting stuff, this is really messed up.

Comment: Why do you have circular imports in the first place?

Comment: I'm using trpc and I wanted to split my routers into different files, since they depend on a variable that I'm initializing in index.js. Shouldn't have done it, but now I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: a) put them in `function`s, not in constants or b) move all constants to a separate module from where both *index.ts* and *b.ts* can import them

Comment: If you could share your actual code, as well as how you are using these modules, we would be able to give better advice

Comment: "*the import is hoisted to the top in* index.ts, *which means* b.ts *code executes first.*" - actually, which of them executes first depends on the entry point of your application, and which of the two modules is imported first there

Comment: Followed @Bergi 's advice, split everything into different files, all imports are now at the top, everything works. Thanks a lot, the code looks better as well.